# Can I make a named function in google sheets that will reference a cell in the sheet it is used in

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, named-function

I am making a named function that needs to reference a cell in the sheet and whenever I make it and type for instance `$D$4` it converts it to `'SheetName'!$D$4`(First sheet's D4) making it to where I can't use the named function in other sheets.

Is there a way I can make it look at the `D4` in the current sheet or do I need to manually make a named function for every sheet that I use it in?

Comment: Share you progress please, what did you try?

Comment: @Osm I was able to find a work around, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out a work around. Basically, instead of directly getting the cells, I used offsets to get those cells for me. For the reference to the offset, I used an argument which I always set to A1. EX: "OFFSET(CELL, 3, 3)" where CELL is the argument set to A1, would give me D4 in that specific sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to pass  whatever range is needed as a argument. For eg, a function named `NAMED_GREATER(cell)` with definition `=(cell>D4*8)` can be
rewritten as

```
NAMED_GREATER(cell, cell2)
```

with formula definition:

```
=cell>cell2*8
```

Where that is not feasible, You can use  [`OFFSET` in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73922826/8404453), when possible. But if `OFFSET` isn't feasible, use `INDIRECT`

`INDIRECT("$D$4")`

This makes `D4` refer to the current sheet's `D4`. However, `OFFSET` is preferred, because unlike string ranges, they auto update based on changes.